# button text change

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

i have two page
 ... the first page include gridview and button(Add new student)

> the first column in gridview is hyperlink(ID) when i click on any ID of students its open the second page and show me the student information

in the second page i have textbox>> and button(update)

so how can i change the text button(update) in the second page to be (add) ?
 when i click  on the button in first page (add new student)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
btnEdit.Text = Request.QueryString["ID"] != null ? "Update" : "Add";
```

Comment: where i must write this code ?
in first page ? or second ? in html or behind code ?

Comment: in the your edit page Page_Load event handler. And, surely, change btnEdit on the name of your Update button

Answer (score 1):

In the `Page_Load` of the second page, do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if(Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
        {
            YourButton.Text = "Update";
        }
        else
        {
            YourButton.Text = "Add";
        }
    }
}
```